# Dollar sign ($) in clojure symbol name

Tags: clojure

I've been writing a clojure parser and come across the follow syntax:

```
(defn key
  "Returns the key of the map entry."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [^java.util.Map$Entry e]
    (. e (getKey)))
```

What does that '$' mean here? Is there any usage for that kind of syntax outside of metadata?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way to access nested classes in Clojure. In this case, you're accessing [`Entry`, which is an interface defined inside the `Map` interface](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Map.java#Map.Entry)

In Java, you'd simply write `java.util.Map.Entry`, in Clojure you need to use the dollar sign: `java.util.Map$Entry`

From the [Clojure documentation on Java interoperability](http://clojure.org/java_interop):

> The '.' special form is the basis for access to Java. It can be considered a member-access operator, and/or read as 'in the scope of'.
>
> If the first operand is a symbol that resolves to a class name, the access is considered to be to a static member of the named class. Note that nested classes are named `EnclosingClass$NestedClass`, per the JVM spec. Otherwise it is presumed to be an instance member and the first argument is evaluated to produce the target object.